# R: Use function arguments as names for list sub elements

Tags: r, list, function, names

Here is a simplified example of what I am trying to do

```
set.seed(1)
a <- rnorm(10)
b <- rnorm(10)

asdf<-function(vec1,vec2){
  mylist <- list(sums = c(vec1 = sum(a), vec2 = sum(b)),
                 products = c(vec1 = prod(a), vec2 = prod(b)))
  return(mylist)
}

asdf(a,b)
```

Here is the output:

```
$sums
vec1     vec2 
1.322028 2.488450 
$products
vec1         vec2 
0.0026236813 0.0003054751
```

The names of the list elements are based on the names I specified when defining the function, not the actual inputs used in the function.  This makes sense, in general, but I would like to know how to change this behavior for a specific problem

My desired output, given inputs `a` and `b` would be

```
$sums
a        b 
1.322028 2.488450 

$products
a            b 
0.0026236813 0.0003054751
```

Whatever the inputs are, be they `c(1,2,3,3,3,123)` and `c(2,1,1,5,7,1)` or `rnorm(10)` and `rpois(10)`, should be returned in the output.

I know how to do the renaming after the function is done, but I want the naming to happen
within the function.  I've been looking at some other questions on SO, but haven't had anything work out quite right.

A few things I've tried without success.

```
asdf<-function(vec1,vec2){
  name1<- deparse(substitute(vec1))
  name2<- deparse(substitute(vec2))
  mylist <- list(sums = c(name1 = sum(a), name2 = sum(b)),
                 products = c(name1 = prod(a), name2 = prod(b)))
  return(mylist)
}

asdf<-function(vec1,vec2){ 
  mylist <- list(sums = c(name1 = sum(a), name2 = sum(b)),
                 products = c(name1 = prod(a), name2 = prod(b)))
  assign(names(mylist(vec1,vec2)$sums,
         c(deparse(substitute(vec1)),deparse(substitute(vec2)))))
  return(mylist)
}
```

It seems I may need to use `get` or `assign` or `match.call`, but I'm out of my league here.

I feel a bit like a dunce reading some of these help pages.  If I don't know enough to understand the help pages, well, I'm not nearly as good at R as I thought I was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `substitute` to capture the names, then `setNames` to setthem.

```
asdf<-function(vec1,vec2){
  nms <- as.character(c(substitute(vec1), substitute(vec2)))

  mylist <- list(sums = c(vec1 = sum(a), vec2 = sum(b)),
                 products = c(vec1 = prod(a), vec2 = prod(b)))

  # return
  lapply(mylist, setNames, nms)
}

asdf(a,b)
```

---

you can put the `setNames` right into the `list()` call above, but that might the code too cumbersome to read

Comment: +1, Just for the sake of learning, can I ask you to provide the code with `setNames` in the `list()` call?  I fooled around with it, but I think I must be extra dense tonight.

Comment: `mylist <- list(sums = setNames(c(sum(a), sum(b)), nms),
                 products = setNames(c(prod(a), prod(b)), nms))`